# Create javascript 2D array of incremental values from 1 - 1000 and second value a random number from 1 - 50

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I need to create a 2D array for some POC work.

The first value of the array needs to go up in single increments between the values 1 to 1000 and the second value needs to be a random number from values 1 to 50.

Comment: Give it a shot, and we'll help you when you get stuck.

Comment: I did here:

var a = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 51);
       
    var a = [i, randNum];
    
}

So almost right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
  array.push([i, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)]);
}
```

To explain how we end up with a random number between 1 and 50:

[`Math.random()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) generates a random floating point number `r` where 0 ≤ `r` < 1. Thus, multiplying that by 50 will result in a number `s` where 0 ≤ `s` < 50. Then we use [`Math.floor()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp), which rounds a decimal down to the nearest integer (so the result will be an integer between 0 and 49 inclusive). Adding 1 to that will give the desired result -- a random integer between 1 and 50.

Comment: @Ryan sorry, I fixed it. That's what happens when I code in a textbox while working in multiple languages at once ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
  array.push([i, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 50)]);
}
```

Personally I prefer to use Math.ceil and have it round up, rather than round it down ***and then*** add one.